# Update a table in Mysql using a form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a simple bug tracker tool.

When you've created a project, you can select a project status (open, in progress, finished).

You can change this status on the project page with this select form, :

```
<form action="classes/changestatus.class.php" method="post">
    <label> Change Project Status </label>
    <select name="status" id="status">
        <option value="open">Open</option>
        <option value="inprogress">In Progress</option>
        <option value="finished">Finished</option>
    </select>
    <input class="small button" value="Change Status" type="submit"> 
</form>
```

The form posts the action to this class:

```
     $status = $_POST['status'];    
     $sql = "UPDATE INTO projects ( status ) VALUES ('$status')";    
     $result = mysql_query( $sql ); 
     $result = mysql_real_escape_string( $sql );     
     $latestID = mysql_insert_id();

     if ( $result ) {
         header('Location: ../projectpage.php?id='.$latestID); 
     } else { 
         echo "There is something wrong. Try again later.";
     }

     mysql_close();
```

So, when you submit the form it will run the query above and go back to the project page, with the changed project status, but this doesn't work.
I always get redirected to the wrong project page and the data doesn't update in the mysql table.

The problem is that I can't get the id, when I have this link for example 'projectpage?id=20', it always redirects me to 'projectpage?id=0'.

Can anyone help me ? I know the code isn't fully sql injection proof and I don't use mysqli, I just like to have an anwser on my question.

Thanks!

Comment: and your code is vulnerable to ___SQL INJECTION___ either properly escape all request or use prepared statements

Comment: Not to mention `$result = mysql_real_escape_string($sql);` will ALWAYS return true...

Comment: Please, please, please, _please_: Stop using `mysql_*` functions, the entire extension is deprecated and will be removed in the near future. Learn how to use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` (the `i` is for _improved_). Could you explain why you're _first_ calling `mysql_query`, and _then_ call `mysql_real_escape_string`? Because that makes _no sense_ at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
$sql="UPDATE projects SET status = '$status', id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)"; 
$latestID = mysql_insert_id();
```

It will works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're not keeping the $id so the this data isn't being transferred. on your form use:

```
<input type='hidden' name='hdnID' value="<?php echo $id;?>"> 
<input class="small button" value="Change Status" type="submit">
```

Then on your form use:

```
$status = $_POST['status'];
$id = $_POST['hdnID'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$sql="UPDATE projects SET status = '$status'";
```

And `mysql_insert_id` will only work when an `INSERT` query is executed.You need an `id` to update it or either to redirect it...If you are giving `id` then you can do like

```
$sql="UPDATE projects SET status = '$status' WHERE id = $id";
```

And redirection will be like

```
header('Location: ../projectpage.php?id='.$id);
```